# reconciling `static` folders in a React / Django / nginx project

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx, create-react-app, nginx-location

I'm working on a rather large project with some colleagues who are making the Django half. I'm working on the React half (created with `create-react-app`, then ejected). Both projects live in the same repo, and are coordinated with nginx to look like one single project from the end user pov. The issue I'm running into is that both projects seem to insist on their static folders being named `static`, which is creating routing issues in the nginx config. Right now the React urls are being routed to one `proxy-pass` port and Django urls to a different port, which is otherwise working fine.

What I'd like to do is either:

1. rename the `PUBLIC_APP` var in the React half so all the React static files can be differentiated by urls of say, `/react-project/static`. So far I've been unable to find a way to do this that consistently renames *all* static files and it seems to be an outstanding React bug.
2. set up nginx to route all `/static/` routes to the Django proxy, and if not found there, then to the React proxy. I have very little nginx experience and can't seem to get the syntax to work. I want something like this:

```
  try_files $uri @django-project
  proxy_pass http://react-project:0000
}

@django-project {
  proxy_pass http://django-project:0000
}
```

Let me know if I didn't give enough info / code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I found a solution to this. By creating a `.env` text file at the root of the React project and adding a `PUBLIC_URL` there, then ALSO adding that same string as both the `basename` in React router and the `homepage` in `package.json` I seem to have forced all static files into a `react-project/static` folder. Before I was sometimes getting a duplicate `react-project/react-project` url but I was kind of flailing madly and I'm not sure how I did that.

Hopefully this is of help to someone else!